# How to ignore node_modules in GitHub action function "hashFiles"?

Tags: github-actions, glob

I'm using the [cache](https://github.com/actions/cache) GitHub action and I'm generating a cache key with the built-in [hashFiles](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#hashfiles) function:

```yaml
key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('./packages/protocol/{,!(node_modules)}**/*') }}-coverage-lcov
```

The command above does not work, however. What I see in the GitHub Actions logs is this:

> Cache saved with key: Linux--coverage-lcov

There is no hash generated, presumably because the glob is incorrect. How can I correctly ignore the `node_modules` folder in the path provided to the `hashFiles` function?

Answer (score 1):

Your paths need to be in *separate* parameters, as shown in the example given on [the hashFiles docs page you linked](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#hashfiles):

```
hashFiles('**/package-lock.json', '**/Gemfile.lock')
```

Aditionally you seem to be missing Some `*` after the end of the `{` and maybe before the `node_modules` depending on your directory setup.

Comment: Does this work for negative paths as well? I.e. `!**/node_modules`?

Comment: There is a [Filter syntax cheat sheet from GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet) which includes `!` so, yeah. You need to encapsulate the term it should negate in parentheses though